# Spring Roo MySQL JDBC Driver

Tags: java, mysql, spring-roo

I'm trying to install MySQL JDBC driver in Spring Roo.  Here is the log:

```
roo> addon search --requiresDescription "#jdbcdriver,driverclass:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
0 found, sorted by rank; T = trusted developer; R = Roo 1.2 compatible
ID T R DESCRIPTION -------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[HINT] use 'addon info id --searchResultId ..' to see details about a search result
[HINT] use 'addon install id --searchResultId ..' to install a specific search result, or
[HINT] use 'addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName TAB' to install a specific add-on version
```

What I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to add the driver, you could add it directly in the pom.xml, e.g.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 6):

In Spring Roo 1.2.5.RELEASE, there seems to be a bug. The add on command shows the MySQL driver to have been successfully installed, but running the DBRE command fails with no driver found.

I have others complaining about this issue as well for this version of Roo.

The only way around that worked for me is to manually copy the MySQL Driver (JAR) into /spring-roo-1.2.5.RELEASE/bundle folder and restarting Spring STS, which is where I am running Roo.

That worked; hope this helps someone in the same boat.

Answer (score 2):

to tell roo to install the jdbc-drive try this:

```
roo> addon search jdbc
9 found, sorted by rank; T = trusted developer; R = Roo 1.2 compatible
ID T R DESCRIPTION -------------------------------------------------------------
01 Y Y 1.2.4.0010 #jdbcdriver driverclass:net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.
       This bundle wraps the standard Maven artifact: jtds-1.2.4.
02 Y Y 5.1.18.0001 #jdbcdriver driverclass:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. This bundle
       wraps the standard Maven artifact: mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.
03 Y Y 10.8.2.2_0001 Derby Client #jdbcdriver
       driverclass:org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver. This bundle wraps the...
04 Y Y 6.7.0.0010 #jdbcdriver driverclass:com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.
       This bundle wraps the standard Maven artifact: jtopen-6.7.
05 Y Y 10.8.2.2_0001 Derby #jdbcdriver
       driverclass:org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver. This bundle wraps...
06 Y Y 9.1.0.901-1_0001 Postgres #jdbcdriver driverclass:org.postgresql.Driver.
       This bundle wraps the standard Maven artifact:...
07 Y Y 9.1.0.901_0001 Postgres #jdbcdriver driverclass:org.postgresql.Driver.
       This bundle wraps the standard Maven artifact:...
08 Y Y 1.3.170.0001 H2 #jdbcdriver driverclass:org.h2.Driver. This bundle wraps
       the standard Maven artifact: h2-1.3.170.
09 Y Y 2.1.6.0020 #jdbcdriver driverclass:org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver. This
       bundle wraps the standard Maven artifact: firebird-2.1.6.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[HINT] use 'addon info id --searchResultId ..' to see details about a search result
[HINT] use 'addon install id --searchResultId ..' to install a specific search result, or
[HINT] use 'addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName TAB' to install a specific add-on version
roo> addon install id --searchResultId 02
```

The ID is the Id in the list...